# How can i convert just a time to utc time in c#?

Tags: c#, timezone

I have a time 5:30 PM , i want to convert this to utc time using c#
For datetime i use the following

```
string dataTimeFormat =  "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
string dateString <passed in as parameter>


dateFormat = settings.Culture ?? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("Culture")?.First() ?? "en-US";
var timeZone = settings.TimeZone ?? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("TimeZone")?.First() ?? string.Empty;
cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(dateFormat);                    
utcDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString, cultureInfo);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeZone))
{
   var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
     return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(utcDate, timeZoneInfo).ToString(dataTimeFormat ?? "G", cultureInfo);
}
```

But I want to do it on just time , so for example if i have a time as 17:30:00.000Z all works fine as this is in UTC , but if i pass in 5:30 PM I want to convert it to a UTC time
How can i do this ?

Comment: Ah, you are aware that the conversion DEPENDS ON DATE unless you do not have any daylight savings time, and even then it may not be unique and thus not be reliable?

Comment: Yes , but  I use it for Salesforce time field not a datetime field. If i send 17:30:00.000Z it shows as 5:30 PM in Salesforce , but if i send 5:30 PM it shows up as a different time. Salesforce expects UTC time

Comment: You still need a referene date for this.

Comment: Also, consider the case where a local time of 17:30 is after 0:00 UTC (for example, on the US west coast. You asked "what if the tome zone is null?" below. The .NET DateTime infrastructure only thinks "local time" during time zone conversions to UTC. Times and Dates are _really hard_. If you want to do this well, consider using [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/)

Comment: Time alone, with no date, is **not enough information** to do the conversion, because TimeZones are not specific enough. The problem is instead of two separate zones for, say, US Central Standard Time (CST) and US Central Daylight Time (CDT), those are the _**same zone**_ and you need to know the date to know which offset to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
string x = dt.ToString("t", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(x).ToString("T"));
```

output:

```
30-07-2023 00:17:02
12:17 AM
00:17:00
```

another eg.

```
string x1 = "5:30 PM";
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(x1).ToString("T"));
```

output

```
17:30:00
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: It doesnt exactly, i want an output of 17:30:00.000  ?

Comment: if the input is like this - "5:30 PM", will the milliseconds and seconds not always be 00:000? If this is the case ":000" can't just be appended?

Comment: yes i have appended

Answer (score 1):

To convert a time (without a date) to UTC, you still need a reference date to ensure daylight saving time (DST) adjustments are handled correctly. If you don't have a date, you can use a default date (e.g., today's date) just for the conversion process. This might not be perfect if the timezone has different UTC offsets at different times of the year due to DST.

Here's how you can convert a time string like "5:30 PM" to UTC:

1. Parse the time string to a `DateTime` object.
2. Attach a date to it (e.g., today's date).
3. Use the timezone to convert the `DateTime` object to UTC.
4. Extract the time from the UTC `DateTime` object.

Here's a code example:

```cs
string timeString = "5:30 PM"; // This is passed in as parameter
string timeZone = settings.TimeZone ?? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("TimeZone")?.First() ?? string.Empty;
string dateFormat = settings.Culture ?? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("Culture")?.First() ?? "en-US";
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(dateFormat);

// Attach today's date to the time string for conversion purposes
DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + timeString, cultureInfo);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeZone))
{
    TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
    DateTime utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localDateTime, timeZoneInfo);

    // Extract just the time from the UTC DateTime object
    string utcTimeString = utcDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    Console.WriteLine(utcTimeString);  // This will give you the converted UTC time.
}
```

Make sure to note that if the local time "5:30 PM" is during daylight saving time in the local timezone, the UTC time might be different if you choose a default date that's outside of daylight saving time. So, the accuracy of this approach depends on the default date chosen if the actual date isn't available.

Comment: what if timezone is null what doi i return in that scenario ?

Comment: Also wouldnt you need to put a Z on the end of time like the following utcDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ssZ");  and get a format like 17:30:00.000Z ?

Comment: Issue i have is that it says 5:30 PM is an invalid time format for xsd:time for Salesforce